# Agenda is not working with timeZone of "Asia/Karachi" !! If we set timeZone as "Asia/Karachi" in repeatEvery, it is still taking "UTC" timezone

Tags: mongodb, datetime, timezone, nestjs, agenda

Is there any way to resolve this issue,
I have created a cron job with repeatEvery, and set timezone as "Asia/Karachi" , timezone updated in database but it is still taking "UTC" timezone for nextRunAt.

Comment: Could you describe how do you set the timezone? Which operating system?

Comment: Hi, and welcome! It's very difficult to understand what you are asking about.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then come back and edit your question and title.  Thanks.